# <lightning:fromattedUrl/> Not working in mobile view

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Earlier I used `<ui:outputURL/>` in my Org, and it's being depreciated in API 47. SF recommending to move with `<lightning:formattedUrl/>`.

Desktop view its working fine and In mobile view`<lightning:formattedUrl/>` is not working as expected.
***Checked on Mobile Device as well***

***CODE***

***`<ui:outputURL/>`***
`<ui:outputURL value="{!dcmnt.attachmentLink}" class="pdfLinkTextDisplay bodyLink boldText" label="{!dcmnt.planDocument.transDocLabel}" target="_blank" />`

***`<lightning:formattedUrl/>`***
`<lightning:formattedUrl value="{!dcmnt.attachmentLink}" class="pdfLinkTextDisplay bodyLink boldText" label="{!dcmnt.planDocument.transDocLabel}" target="_blank" />`

***ISSUE***

***Desktop***
[image: Desktop]

***Mobile - Not Working***
[image: Mobile]

As per my analysis, In mobile view it append ***member/s*** also from the Domain URL.

***URL***
[image: Domain URL]

Any Idea how can I resolve this?

Anyone insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.